# Convertir a ejecutable un archivo py y MySQL

Tags: mysql, python

Estoy realizando un proyecto en python y mysql, quiero convertir a ejecutable (.exe) pero con pyinstaller solo puedo ejecutar el archivo py y no con la base de datos que uso en mysql, ¿alguien que pueda ayudarme?, gracias de antemano

Comment: Tu pregunta puede estar relacionada con esta otra: [Python - ¿Es posible crear una aplicación de escritorio usando django?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/2333/250)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas recibiendo puntuaciones negativas dada la poca información que has proporcionado respecto de lo que quieres hacer, dicho esto voy a ver si entiendo lo que quieres y si puedo ayudarte.

En primer lugar no indicas claramente el sistema operativo en el que estas trabajando aunque al poner que quieres convertir a (.exe) voy a suponer que estas en windows, otra cosa interesante seria que ademas de indicar el sistema operativo también indicases la version, por ejemplo 7 o 10, etc. Para este ejemplo puede no ser relevante pero para otras cuestiones seguro que si.

Otra cosa que no haces es indicar exactamente que estas ejecutando y que error te esta dando esa ejecución por lo que es complicado saber si directamente el problema que tienes es sobre como usar pyinstaller o un problema de sintaxis.

Si puedes indica que hace tu código, o pégalo para poder evaluarlo y así saber cual es el objetivo final del mismo.

Por ultimo, entiendo que estas usando el siguiente comando para crear tu ejecutable:

```
python pyinstaller.py tucodigo.py
```

Y que esto esta generando tu ejecutable.

Comment: Ya converti mi archivo python a ejecutable, lo que quiero es que trabaje con mi base de datos sin instalar mysql, como hago eso